# Project search for names then copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code set up where I have it searching for certain names with autofilter on one sheet and then if the names are there, then it will copy all visible cells on the sheet and then paste it to a defined range on a different sheet. The code will recognize that the name I want it to search for are there and when I break out the code, it will copy the range but when I have it insert the copied range, it just inserts a blank row instead of the copied range. Been spinning my wheels trying to figure out why it's not working. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub UpdateEmail()

Dim dstSheet As Worksheet
Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
Dim srcRng As Range
Dim lRow As Long

Set srcRng2 = Sheets("Paste").Range("G:G")

With ThisWorkbook
    Set srcSheet = .Sheets("Paste")
    Set dstSheet = .Sheets("Email")
End With


            
'John Update
Set rngJohn = srcRng2.Find("*" & "John" & "*")


If rngJohn Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No deals for John Doe"
 
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            
            Else
            
With srcSheet
 lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
.Rows(1).AutoFilter 7, "*" & "John" & "*"
Set srcRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lRow, 8))
srcRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy


Range("JohnRow").Insert Shift:=xlDown

            

End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
srcSheet.ShowAllData
End If

'Jane Update
Set rngJane = srcRng2.Find("*" & "Jane" & "*")


If rngJane Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No deals for Jane Doe"
 
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            
            Else
            
With srcSheet
 lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
.Rows(1).AutoFilter 7, "*" & "Jane" & "*"
Set srcRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lRow, 8))
srcRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy


Range("JaneRow").Insert Shift:=xlDown

            
            
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
srcSheet.ShowAllData
End If

'Jeff Update
Set rngJeff = srcRng2.Find("*" & "Jeff" & "*")


If rngJeff Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No deals for Jeff"
 
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            
            Else
            
With srcSheet
 lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
.Rows(1).AutoFilter 7, "*" & "Jeff" & "*"
Set srcRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lRow, 8))
srcRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy


Range("JeffRow").Insert Shift:=xlDown

            
            
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
srcSheet.ShowAllData
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you try doing that manually you'll see it doesn't work - you can Paste but not insert.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If I manually filter the rows on one page for just John and copy and insert the copied cells on the other page, it work's fine. Every other method I can find anywhere else also utilizes insert shift=xldown

Comment: Only works for me if the copied range is contiguous (ie. only has a single Area)